How can I use different color-schemes on different elements, with the browser/user default colors?
I'd like most of my site to use the user's preference for color-scheme and the user or browser's default colors. But there's one element that I want to always use the dark color-scheme, and the user or browser's default colors for that.
I tried to set one color-scheme on :root (color-scheme: light dark in the real code, but color-scheme: light only in the example below to show the issue to viewers of this question with a dark color scheme) and color-scheme: dark only on the element that I want to be dark regardless of the surrounding color scheme.
In Firefox 126.0.1 at least, that seemed to have no effect at all on the dark element. However, if I explicitly set color and background-color to their <system-color> defaults, it seems to work.
Is there any way to make it work without manually specifying every single default color? I'd rather not do that, because if a new one is added in the future, I'd rather get the default for that new one automatically.


:root { color-scheme: light only; }
.dark { color-scheme: dark only; }
.explicit-color { color: CanvasText; background-color: Canvas; }
<p>light</p>
<p class="dark">should be dark</p>
<p class="dark explicit-color">actually dark</p>



